# docker unable to read terraform files

Tags: docker, terraform

I am trying to deploy terraform on docker, however my docker container seems unable to read  main.tf file and throws error like **provide: not found** and **region: not found**. I am providing my sample dockerfile and main.tf, please suggest where I am going wrong

Dockerfile snippet, can't share complete file here but the snippet contains all terraform related code

```
RUN apt-get -y install wget unzip
RUN wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.11.11/terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip
RUN unzip terraform_0.11.11_linux_amd64.zip
RUN mv terraform /usr/local/bin/

ADD main.tf /usr/local/bin/terraform

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/terraform

RUN terraform init
RUN terraform apply -auto-approve /usr/local/bin/terraform -var 'access_key=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}' -var 'secret_key=${AWS_SECRET_KEY}'
```

main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "region-name"
}

resource "aws_instance" "aws_testing" {
  ami = "ami-name"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  #Was using variables.tf ealier but that was laso not being read by 
  #docker, so hard coded these values
  subnet_id = "my-subnet5"

  #Security group
  security_groups = ["smy-security-group"]

}
```

The expected result is for this to create an AWS instance. 
Also, the terraform script runs fine independently, it's with docker I am getting this error

Comment: Could you show the place where you put the main.tf into the container? All I can see from the snippet above is that you download / unzip terraform. But there is no mention of the main.tf file which is clearly needed inside the container when running the terraform command.

Comment: ADD main.tf /usr/local/bin/terraform

this line would copy main variable to terraform, isn't it, or do I need to execute RUN command from /us/local/bin path

Comment: please have a look at my answer. `ADD main.tf /usr/local/bin/terraform` doesn't work as terraform is an executable and not a folder (you give +x in Dockerfile). `ADD main.tf /usr/local/bin` is possible with `WORKDIR /usr/local/bin` afterwards because then the main.tf is in the same directory where you execute the `terraform` command. If you want to put main.tf anywhere else you can simply add the path to main.tf within the single terraform commands (see answer).

Comment: I figured that during my multiple attempts...see that you have given same suggestion..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell terraform where your terraform files are located.

You can do so by setting WORKDIR in the Dockerfile like:

```
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
```

(I think you have a mistake in your snippet above. main.tf is in /usr/local/bin .. not in /usr/local/bin/terraform.. right? So this will work because main.tf is in the same directory where the terraform command is executed.)

Or you can specify the path in the terraform commands like:

```
terraform init /usr/local/bin
```